# Fatal Python Error on Startup (Not Responding)

Tags: python, startup-file

Can someone help me? Every time I try to run blender it keeps I get the same error, I tried to install blender as a zip file, install a previous version that I know worked for me before (on the same computer as now), install blender from Steam, and search all over the internet, here is the error message:

```
found bundled python: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender/2.78/python
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize unable to load the file system codec
 File "C:\Python27\Lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
  raise CodecRegisteryError,\
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Current thread 0x00002a20 (most recent call first)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like Blender is using a very old version of Python. Try taking any path in `C:\Python27` off your `PATH` environment variable.

I'm assuming you're running Windows 10, since you clearly use Windows but don't mention which version. Right-click on "This PC", then choose "Properties". In the next screen, click "Advanced System Settings", then click on "Environment Variables". In both the box "User variables for {your name}" and "System variables" doubleclick on "Path" (or any other capitalisation) and remove anything that starts with `C:\Python27`.

You may want to write down the original values you removed, just so you can restore them later.

Comment: Can you help me do that? please?

Comment: I've updated the comment.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! Apparently I added Python as an environment variable when trying to set up a server using python for another device to connect to. I took it out of there and blender now works perfectly! thanks! Also, sorry for that question, but I already figured out how to do that! (I'm a geek in learning).

Comment: You're welcome :) Don't forget to mark this as the answer to your question.

Answer (score -1):

When I was trying to use blender, I had a python path as an environment variables. Therefore, blender was unable to use it (I think), so I deleted the path and blender started working.

P.S I may be wrong, but the python path in environment variables was what causing me the problem.

Comment: If someone gives you the correct answer, please mark that answer as "accepted". Don't write your own answer too.